# Create iframes from original page content with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am trying to dynamically "rewrite" an entire page to a set of iframes. I want a music player bar at the bottom iframe and the original page "rewritten" in an iframe above/behind that. Almost just like [SMC player](http://scmplayer.net/). I feel like I'm close but I am a jQuery novice.. So any pointers will be greatly appreciated beforehand.

Here's the main part that creates the iframes that's not working correctly.

```
var oldpage =  "<html>" + $("html").html() + "</html>";
$('body').html( "<iframe frameborder='0' id='content' allowtransparency='true' name='content'></iframe>" );
$('#content').contents().find('html').html(oldpage);
$('body').append("<iframe id='stratus' allowtransparency='true' frameborder='0' scrolling='0'>");
```

I'm trying to load the entire original html on line 1. Then creating iframes and trying to inject the oldbody variable into the new iframe #content. The iframes are created but the #content iframe has a blank body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why, but you can't replace the whole HTML element, only its contents:

```
// create raw frame
var frame = $('<iframe id="maincontent" style="position:absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 50%; height: 50%;"><html></html></iframe>');

// store a copy of current document contents
var copiedHead = $('head').clone();
var copiedBody = $('body').clone();

// empty the current document
$(':not(iframe) body *').remove();

// load the copy into the frame;
// it's not possible to replace the whole HTML element;
// using plain JS DOM function here, since jQuery would strip out any SCRIPT and STYLE tags
frame.load(function(){
    $(this).contents().find('html')[0].replaceChild(copiedHead[0] , $(this).contents().find('head')[0]);
    $(this).contents().find('html')[0].replaceChild(copiedBody[0] , $(this).contents().find('body')[0]);
}).appendTo('body');
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you! It is odd you that can't select the entire html content.

Comment: Now I have one other problem. Maybe I'll start a new post but when I click a link in the #content iframe it just reloads the main page and doesn't follow the link.